# Do I need to create an executor service everytime I need async computation aside from the main thread in java?

Tags: java, completable-future

Consider the following:

```
public void run (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("testing async");
        
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->
        {
            return secondfunc("");
        }, ex).thenApply( (val)->
        {                                                    
            return secondfunc(val);
        }).thenApply( (val) -> 
        {
            return thirdfunc(val);
        }).thenAccept((val)->
        {
            System.out.println(val);
            ex.shutdown();
        });
        
        System.out.println("done testing async");                
    }
```

Output would be:

```
testing async
done testing async
200 200 -->println from fisrt method
200 200 -->println from second method
200 200 -->println from third method
Done Post twoDone Post twoDone Post three -->result on the accept
```

whereas, in this example:

```
public void run (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("testing async");
   
    
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->
    {
        return secondfunc("");
    }).thenApply( (val)->
    {                                                    
        return secondfunc(val);
    }).thenApply( (val) -> 
    {
        return thirdfunc(val);
    }).thenAccept((val)->
    {
        System.out.println(val);
    });
    
    System.out.println("done testing async");                
}
```

the result is the folling:

```
testing async
done testing async
```

The question, Do I need to create an executor service everytime I need async computation aside from the main thread in java?, why is this different in JavaScript?

Comment: what does the documentation of `supplyAsync` without an Executor say? "Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier." What kind of Threads does `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` produce? daemon threads. Does the VM wait for daemon thread before exiting? No.

Comment: Yours is mostly the answer, now I understand that these kind of functions create Daemons, and these are background supporting task that the VM does not keep when the main (or any other) terminates. If I need things to run in parallel I will create an executor and thats it.
Now, another question comes to mind. How many threads should I create in the newFixedThreadPool?, or, do you have any link or documentation that I can read about this subject?

Comment: this is a very complicated question. We use 2 to 3 for various tasks that we have. Measure and you will find out. Again, its not easy at all

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you care if the tasks complete and are successful? If so see answer below - you need to add each CompletableFutire to a list and then wait for them to complete and check the status with CompletableFuture.get(). (2) Do you want any inflight threads to continue and finish if your program terminates? That will dictate whether or not you want daemon threads or not. Don't conflate the two concerns.

Comment: You don’t need to create a new executor service. You just have to wait for the completion if you want your program not to terminate before completion. E.g. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> secondfunc("")) .thenApply(val -> secondfunc(val)) .thenApply(val -> thirdfunc(val)) .thenAccept(val -> System.out.println(val)) .join();`

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these are "correct". CompletableFuture.supplyAsync returns you a CompletableFuture instance. You need to block on that instance and wait for the tasks to complete with CompletableFuture.get or another method which waits for the tasks/threads to complete. Basically your program is ending before the other threads complete and that's why you are not seeing the output. Read the JavaDoc for CompletableFuture.supplyAsync to see the difference in the two signatures you are calling.